# Is electron a wave with a position?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, waves, subatomic

I am learning Quantum Mechanical model of atom.There is a statement in my textbook which says

> "We consider the electrons to not revolve around the nucleus but as a
> wave present around the nucleus. The possibility of finding an
> electron around the nucleus is maximum"

Now my question is  since electron is a wave around the nucleus so what  does it mean to have the possibility of finding an
electron?

Let me put it in this way

When I turn on the  light bulb in my room, "light"(which is also a wave ) is present everywhere, it doesn't make sense to ask what's the possibility of finding "light" at one corner of the bed.

Comment: "*is present everywhere, it doesn't make sense to ask what's the possibility of finding "light" at one corner of the bed.*" Isn't this only because you are really slow and light is very fast? And photons are far smaller than you can individually see? When you turn on the lamp, light takes time to reach every corner of the room. Also shadows. And you can only perceive *enormous* areas that are illuminated that contain many many photons rather than individual photons.

Comment: Btw it has been proved that light may propagate like a wave when the wave doesnt interact with anything during its route to the destination but it is absorbed and emitted like a particle

Answer (score 2):

When you turn on an ordinary light bulb, *many, many* photons (particles of light) are emitted, so you have the illusion that the energy of a beam of light is continuous. But an overwhelming number of experiments have been done where people have observed individual photons, so it is now taken as a well-established fact that light comes in discrete packets, and it *does* make sense to talk about the probability of finding one of those packets at a particular location. Perhaps the most dramatic example is the [double slit experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment), where individual photons are observed arriving on a screen. After many photons arrive, the distribution of detected photons matches the probability distribution predicted from quantum mechanics.

The reason you think electrons are different is mostly the Pauli exclusion principle, which says that two fermions can't occupy the same quantum state. Since photons are bosons, they don't obey the Pauli, and many photons can be packed into the same state -- this is what you perceive as light when you turn on a light bulb. Electrons, on the other hand, *can't* occupy the same state, and so we don't ever perceive an "electron wave" made of many electrons. Instead, we only really see individual electrons, and quantum mechanics says that in general we can't know the electron's position exactly at all times, but only the probability that the electron will be at a certain place at a certain time.

The same quantum mechanical laws of motion apply to light as apply to electrons$^\star$, but this is less obvious from everyday life because the Pauli exclusion principle creates a difference in how we experience these two different types of particles.

---

$^\star$ Of course the specific equations are different for light and electrons, but what I'm saying is that both can be understood within the same framework of quantum mechanics. Much like a mass on a spring and a ball falling from a tower obey different equations, but (in introductory physics courses) both are described in the framework of Newtonian mechanics.